# Type or Types for the examples below?

Tags: grammar

Brown bears are one of the largest types of bear.

Brown bears are one of the largest type of bear.

Comment: *types* - where people differ is on whether it should be *type(s) of bear* or *type(s) of bears*.

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "type" at all. That sounds as if you're speaking of a machine. The proper term is "species". Or informally, I wouldn't mind "kind". (The fact that the sentence you give calls for any of those being in the plural stands.)

Answer (score 1):

Since the bear type is "brown bear" and not "brown bears," I would write:

> The brown bear is one of the largest types of bear.

Example:

> It is a close call, but the polar bear is generally considered the
>   largest bear on Earth. ([loc.gov](https://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/mysteries/bear.html))

Comment: This is not the only context in which an animal (and plant) species is correctly used in the singular to refer to a collective. E.G. *The Malayan jungle contains tiger, monkey, and leopard cat but less elephant than was once the case. You will also find all you ever want of wild banana and orchid*.